# JPA using alternative "persistence.xml"

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, ejb

I know that with the instruction:

```
Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistence-unit-name");
```

The JPA persistence mechanism reads the "persistence.xml" file, looks for the persistence unit called "persistence-unit-name", and constructs the EntityManagerFactory based on it.

My question is, how can I force JPA to **take a file different from "persistence.xml"**?? for example, "persistence-test.xml".

Comment: Because I wan to use an alternative persistence.xml for my tests.

Comment: @edutesoy You can have multiple Persistence Units inside the same persistence.xml file and use the appropriate one in your tests.

Comment: There is some bug in Maven I have encountered that sometimes (randomly) picks the wrong persistence.xml file during tests.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is no standardized JPA way to do this, although individual JPA providers may provide a way. I would suggest the standard way to have a different class path for main and test.

For example, if you use Maven, and you have two `META-INF/persistence.xml` files, one in `src/main/resources` and one in `src/test/resources`, tests will pick up the one in `src/test/resources`, because Maven puts test classes / resources ahead of main classes / resources in the classpath. You can easily configure Ant to work in similar ways.

If you need more advanced logic, consider using [Spring's JPA support](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-jpa). It will let you deal with advanced situations like [integrating multiple persistence.xml files](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-jpa-multiple-pu).

Comment: persistence.xml file is used from src/test/resources only if I run mvn test command. As soon as you run mvn install, your tests are also run, and the file is taken from src/main/resources which causes a problem.

Comment: @Alexandr that's not how Maven works. When you trigger a lifecycle phase, all phases up to and including that phase are executed. The execution of the test phase is exactly the same, independent of whether you start Maven with test or install. See https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 15):

In EclipseLink you can do the following:

```
Properties pros = new Properties();

pros.setProperty(PersistenceUnitProperties.ECLIPSELINK_PERSISTENCE_XML, 
                 "META-INF/persistence-alternative.xml");


EntityManagerFactory factory = 
    Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("pu-name", pros);
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can. The long way of doing this is:

- Create a Factory that will read your `persistence-test.xml` and render a `Map<String, String>` properties, and.
- Call [`Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(persistenceUnitName, Map properties)`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/persistence/Persistence.html#createEntityManagerFactory%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Map%29). That way, it reads from the `properties` map instead of it reading from `persistence.xml`.

Answer (score 2):

So we want to have 2 separate `persistence.xml` files. One should be read only by production configuration, and the other for tests. The idea is to **rename or hide the production** files.

**War solution**

Don't put `persistence.xml` in `src\main\resources\META-INF\`. Instead put it into `src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\classes\META-INF\`. That's the location where the file should be and in this place it won't be visible by tests.

This solution works for me in gradle environment, but I hope in others would do too.

**Jar solution**

Rename the production file to `persistence-ee.xml`. Now we're done with the test configuration. For production we must employ some processing. Each environment may have its own way, that's how I do it in gradle:

```
tasks.withType(Jar) {
  rename { fileName ->
    fileName == "persistence-ee.xml" ? "persistence.xml" : fileName;
  }
}
```

In my applications having the `persistence.xml` file for production is necessary only at deployment time, that is in jar/war packages. And these are the only places where this file is visible. Without double `persistence` I couldn't start my database. The main reason was using `jta-data-source`, the other: 2 separate named persistence units.

Comment: You saved my life! I have been struggling with this issue for a week and god only knows how long I would have been struggling with it if I hadn't seen your answer. It worked for me like a charm after I moved the 'test' persistence.xml to `src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\classes\META-INF\`. Thank you very very very much!

Answer (score 1):

If you were using OpenEJB to drive your testing, you could do exactly what you want using whichever JPA provider you want.  Similar question and the related answer here:

[How to instruct Maven to ignore my main/resources/persistence.xml in favor of test/...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862853/how-to-instruct-maven-to-ignore-my-main-resources-persistence-xml-in-favor-of-tes/3908512#3908512)

Answer (score 1):

You can configure Hibernate without using persistence.xml at all in Spring like like this:

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean()
{
Map<String, Object> properties = new Hashtable<>();
properties.put("javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action",
"none");
HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
adapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"); //you can change this if you have a different DB
LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(adapter);
factory.setDataSource(this.springJpaDataSource());
factory.setPackagesToScan("package name");
factory.setSharedCacheMode(SharedCacheMode.ENABLE_SELECTIVE);
factory.setValidationMode(ValidationMode.NONE);
factory.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
return factory;
}
```

Since you are not using persistence.xml, you should create a bean that returns DataSource which you specify in the above method that sets the data source:

```
@Bean
public DataSource springJpaDataSource()
{
DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost/SpringJpa");
dataSource.setUsername("tomcatUser");
dataSource.setPassword("password1234");
return dataSource;
}
```

Then you use `@EnableTransactionManagement` annotation over this configuration file. Now when you put that annotation, you have to create one last bean:

```
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager()
{
return new JpaTransactionManager(
this.entityManagerFactoryBean().getObject());
}
```

Now, don't forget to use `@Transactional` Annotation over those method that deal with DB.

Lastly, don't forget to inject `EntityManager` in your repository (This repository class should have `@Repository` annotation over it).

Comment: I don't this works if you need to use jtaDataSource on production server. Then you need persistence.xml and hibernate would find it and process, during tests.