# How to test multiple maven project?

Tags: maven, junit

I have created multiple maven modules (e.g.: entity, service, repository, facade) , those jar contain all my business logic and I will package them  as jar. Then I create a projectA which will depend on all jar file and package as war file. Everything is okay, but question is : How to test my individual jar component as there is not persistence.mxl in jar.  PThe persistence.xml is only located in projectA. Please help...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7227898/6309 might help

Comment: The question is what you exactly like to test? First you should think about unit testing within the appropriate module...If you are talking about persistence.xml that we are in the area of integration testing...