# Entity with table possibly missing in some environments

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.1

I have an entity representing generic users, stored in a table that is filled only on lower environments.
Of course, that shouldn't  be used in production, and to be sure we don't make a mistake, the mock table even doesn't exist in production environment.

In order to present theses generic users in an admin screen, I created a GenericUser entity that i've mapped on the table "GENERIC_USER".
My problem is, even if i don't use this entity in production (by conditioning it to environment parameters), the entity would still be present in the code, and the webapp will complain at startup (and then fail) the table GENERIC_USER is missing.

Is there a way to ask JPA to ignore the non presence of a given table depending on a parameter ?

Switching off the whole validation of the scheman (removing hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto="validate") is not an option for me.

Thanks

Comment: How you configure which entities are scanned? (Config in code, persistence XML, spring auto-configuration)

Comment: By auto detection. No Spring.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure which entities are detected.
With Spring, this is trivial with @EntityScan annotation.

Without spring:

- If you are using persistence.xml, you will have a hard time - AFAIU you cannot define where to look for persistence.xml, you can only provide a correct one for different environments during build/deployment. See [JPA using alternative “persistence.xml”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227814/jpa-using-alternative-persistence-xml)
- Alternatively, you can try to configure JPA/Hibernate without persistence.xml

  - [How to bootstrap JPA programmatically without the persistence.xml configuration file](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-bootstrap-jpa-programmatically-without-the-persistence-xml-configuration-file/)
  - [How to bootstrap Hibernate without the persistence.xml file](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-bootstrap-hibernate-without-the-persistence-xml-file/)

You can also try to pull Spring as a dependency, not convert your app to Spring, just use `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`.

See [LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227814/jpa-using-alternative-persistence-xml#answer-43245235)

Comment: I'm gonna test these propositions and will get back to you.
Thanks !