# using Spring's persistenceXmlLocation without <class> in persistence.xml

Tags: spring, jpa, persistence.xml

### My question:

Is there a way to tell Spring/JPA to automatically detect classes annotated with @Entity?

### Background:

This is my configuration of the entityManagerFactory

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

... and this is my persistence.xml ...

```
<persistence-unit name="foo">
  <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
  <properties>
    <property name="hibernate..." value="..."/>
    <property ...
  </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

This configuration is working. But: When I add the following line to my entityManagerFactory configuration

```
<property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="META-INF/persistence.xml" />
```

JPA doesn't find my classes annotated with @Entity. So, I get Exceptions like this one:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: foo.Bar
```

where foo.Bar is a class annotated with @javax.persistence.Entity

When I now add

```
<class>foo.Bar</class>
```

to my persistence.xml, everything's fine again. But why do I have to specify my classes in persistence.xml when using persistenceXmlLocation and otherwise not?

Note: You might ask why I want to use persistenceXmlLocation: It would solve [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385532/how-to-configure-jpa-for-testing-in-maven).

Comment: I found another solution for my problem. I simply moved all connection parameters from persistence.xml to spring's bean configuration. With this I can use a single persistence.xml for testing, development and production and don't have to provide persistenceXmlLocation. Nevertheless I want to know why the <class>es are required when using persistenceXmlLocation and otherwise not.

Comment: Hi @Ethan Leroy can you provide me the details on how you maintained different database connection parmas for prod and dev in spring bean config? It would be a great help.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't say exactly what was where, so maybe I'm wrong, but it looks like you feel into the trap I fell into.  The **location** of the persistence.xml file defines where Spring (or any JPA provider) will look for @Entity classes by default.  From the [JPA spec](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/persistence-2_0-final-spec.pdf), section 8.2.1

> **A persistence.xml file defines a persistence unit. The persistence.xml file is located in the
>   META-INF directory of the root of the persistence unit.** It may be used to specify managed persistence
>   classes included in the persistence unit, object/relational mapping information for those classes, and
>   other configuration information for the persistence unit and for the entity manager(s) and entity manager factory for the persistence unit. This information may be defined by containment or by reference,
>   as described below.
>
> The object/relational mapping information can take the form of **annotations on the managed persistence
>   classes included in the persistence unit**, an orm.xml file contained in the META-INF directory of the
>   root of the persistence unit, one or more XML files on the classpath and referenced from the persistence.xml file, or a combination of these.
>   **The managed persistence classes may either be contained within the root of the persistence unit; or they
>   may be specified by reference—i.e., by naming the classes, class archives, or XML mapping files
>   (which in turn reference classes) that are accessible on the application classpath; or they may be specified by some combination of these means.**

So although the field is called persistenceXmlLocation, it probably should be called persistenceXmlName, because the purpose is to be able to create a persistence.xml file with a non-standard name so that the EE container will not pick it up.  It still serves as the marker for where to look for Entity classes.

Answer (score 0):

(From Y.Lev)
When the entityManagerFactory bean in spring-beans.xml comes with location property and also with 'classpath:' directive:
      
It doesn't matter where in the class path (When in eclipse put under [bin] or [build]) to put it.

1) Under eclipse: persistence.xml under \WebContent\WEB-INF\classes\persistence.xml
2) Under Tomcat : persistence.xml under \WEB-INF\classes\persistence.xml
3) When not in WEB project put anywhere under [bin] or [build].

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" 
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
      lazy-init="false" p:dataSource-ref="dataSource">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="empPU" />
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:persistence.xml"/>
</bean>
```

The persistence.xml file Should be MANUALLY COPIED somewhere under classpath
 ..\bin\persistence.xml 
 OTHERWISE it is ignored !!!

Answer (score -1):

For the following exception:
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to resolve persistence unit root URL
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.determineDefaultPersistenceUnitRootUrl(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:452)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.preparePersistenceUnitInfos(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:343)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.afterPropertiesSet(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:325)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:224)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
        ... 14 more

In my case, the jar itself included withing it the META-INF/persistence.xml which Spring was not finding given the hint:

Finally, I did the following:

java -classpath ".;my-jarThatIncludesTheMetaInfPersistence.jar" main arguments...

and the trick was adding the "." to the classpath.
Then spring found the xml file in the classpath.

Comment: Looks like another issue that has nothing to do with my question here.

Comment: Lol, probably posted on the wrong stack overflow tab, when I was googling why spring was returning avax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to resolve persistence unit root URL .   :) Sorry for that.

Comment: In any case, as for entity detection, I suppose that you are well aware that in the persistence.xml under a persistence unit you have both <class> and <jar-file> elements, right? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnbrj/index.html  Class is fine grained and faster. Jar-file is coarse grained and low maintenance. Cheers.