# Mockito: How to match a String and List<String> arguments

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I'm basically trying to verify whether the correct parameters are being invoked in a method.

Here's a snippet of the code I'm trying to test:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(User.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.in("type", Arrays.asList("employee", "supervisor");
```

Verifying this using:

```
Mockito.verify(mockSession).createCriteria(User.class);
Mockito.verify(mockCriteria).add(Restrictions.in("type", Arrays.asList("employee", "supervisor"));
```

The first verify statement works. The second doesn't because, I believe, that the JVM detects two different `List` objects being compared to. However, when I change the second verify statement to:

```
Mockito.verify(mockCriteria).add(Restrictions.in("type", Mockito.anyList());
```

It works like a charm. However, I do want to ensure that the two Strings, employee and supervisor, are inside the `List` and that won't happen by using `Mockito.anyList()`.

How do I get this to work?

EDIT: Please take note that I do not wish to only verify whether a List has been passed. I want to ensure that the correct Strings are passed inside that List as well

Comment: @AndyTurner No it doesn't. I need to ensure that the Strings "employee" and "supervisor" are inside the List. That's how I want to test it. If I just wanted to test if a List is passed then I already have that covered

Comment: Sorry, misread the question. If you want to verify something about the argument, you can use `ArgumentCaptor`, and then inspect what that captured.

Comment: Will try it out. Thanks! Never encountered `ArgumentCaptor` before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, here you cannot easily check what you want to check with matchers.

[Mockito matchers work via side-effects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22822512/1426891), where a call to a matcher tells Mockito to use the matcher rather than testing equality. That means that **Mockito matchers don't work at all when nested within objects like Criterion**.

```
verify(mockCriteria).add(
     Restrictions.in("type", Arrays.asList("employee", "supervisor"));
```

In the above, you don't use matchers, you're verifying that `mockCriteria.add` is called with an object that `equals` the Criterion you specify. However, if the returned Criterion doesn't override `equals` (and `hashCode`) then it will only test that the instances are the same—which will never be true here, because you're creating a new one in the `verify` statement.

```
verify(mockCriteria).add(Restrictions.in("type", anyList()));
```

Here, it *looks like* you're verifying that `mockCriteria.add` is called with any list, but `anyList()` actually tells Mockito to skip checking for one parameter and returns the dummy value `null`. You then create a Criterion where "type" in `null`, and then Mockito sees one `any` matcher on the stack for a one-argument method call, discards the newly-created invalid Criterion, and just checks that `add` was called at all. It looks like everything's working, but your `mockCriteria` could receive literally any parameter including `null` and the test would still pass. (If you were using a second matcher, or if `add` took two parameters, you would get `InvalidUseOfMatchersException` instead of your false positive.)

To make this work with Mockito matchers, you would need to write your own Hamcrest matcher that matches the entire Criterion, and then use `argThat` to let Mockito match arguments with it.

---

As Andy Turner mentioned, one way to solve this is to use `ArgumentCaptor`:

```
ArgumentCaptor<Criterion> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Criterion.class);
verify(mockCriteria).add(captor.capture());
Criterion criterion = captor.getValue();
// assert against criterion
```

However, be warned that this may be of limited use: [Criterion](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Criterion.html) doesn't have a lot of properties you can inspect. You may need to use `toString()`, as in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9212131/1426891).

Comment: This was the approach that I've went with. :)