# How to JUnit test the jpa-code using javadb without modifying the original db?

Tags: java, jpa, junit

I'm using JPA to store my java objects in a database using javadb.

Now i've written JUnit tests to check whether the objects are correctly stored and removed etc. from the javadb.

The problem is that modifications to the database in previous tests impact later tests and, more importantly, obviously modify the database that i'm using for my application.

One solution i found was reversing the transaction for each test, but since several of the methods i'm testing already commit their transaction I don't think this would work for me.

I also thought about creating a backup by storing all the data in a file and restoring the database afterwards or making a created persistence.xml with a different jdbc.url value (that will somehow be used when i'm running the tests instead of the original) and creating a separate database.

But i've got  no idea how to make either of those solutions work or if they are even good solutions.

So could anyone explain to me how to exactly go around avoiding modifications to the original database while running these tests?

Comment: Are modifications to the code under test to have that code not do the commit acceptable? That would allow the test to decide whether to commit or rollback.

Comment: I'd recommend having a separate test database. You can use something like DBUnit to populate it with the relevant data for each test. http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/

Comment: It might be if there is no other way to achieve this, but i'm actually testing on an abstraction (interface implemented by this class) and it's really undesirable to change what the methods do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just using maven with a seperate persistence.xml that configured a different javadb database purely for running tests as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385532/how-to-configure-jpa-for-testing-in-maven).

I didn't use DBUnit as [Alan Hay's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37240806/how-to-junit-test-the-jpa-code-using-javadb-without-modifying-the-original-db#comment62011393_37240806) suggested, because of time constraints, but this seems a valid option as well.