# I can't find resolve PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, intellij-idea, persistent

I found some solutions in the forum, but they not working for me.
The problem is that when I run main method I receive this exception - [image]

> PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager

On the imane is my persistance.xml file pat but it's not working. I try to change file path to web/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF, but its's still not working.

Here my full persistance.xml source

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.1">

    <persistence-unit name="StudentPU">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>com.classes.StudentBean</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/Students"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="doncho"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""/>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults"
                      value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And one more thing? Why **HibernatePersistence** is stricken?
I resolve "stricken" mistake like that - [image]
Is it correct?
But anyway the PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager still there.

I tryed - [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158159/no-persistence-provider-for-entitymanager-named) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385532/how-to-configure-jpa-for-testing-in-maven) - nothings happened

I would be grateful for any ideas to resolve this error because @Entity method is important to me.

Best regards,

D. Balamjiev

Comment: You can try to debug in class Persistence. There must be a reason, but I don't see it.

Comment: "stricken" ?! You mean deprecated? Maybe because it has presumably been replaced with something else ... aka what deprecated means

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workig method for me is to create this path in my project tree:
**web/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml**

This is working path when We create Web Applications with IntelliJ.